# toggleClass on checkbox select unselect when it is in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, toggleclass

I want to change the class of my row in ng-repeat to active when a checkbox is tick or remove the active class on checkbox unselect

```
<table><tbody><tr><td><b>S No.</td><td><b>Name</td><td><b>Email-Id</td><td><b>Birthday</td><td><b>Contact</td><td><b>Action</td></tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="(key,user) in users"  ng-style="myStyle"  ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedRow}">
                      <blockquote><td><input type ="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" ng-class="active">{{key+1}}</td><td>{{user.name}}</td> 


        <td>{{user.email}}</td><td>{{user.dob }}  </td> <td>{{contact }}</td><td><a href="" ng-click="removeUser(user)"  > remove | </a><a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor($index)" >  Edit user</a></td> 
                     </input>

                  <input type="button" value="Red" ng-click="myStyle={background:'red'}">     

                    </blockquote> </tr>  
                      </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you HTML to following. You need to set isChecked state for each row.

```
<table><tbody><tr><td><b>S No.</td><td><b>Name</td><td><b>Email-Id</td><td><b>Birthday</td><td><b>Contact</td><td><b>Action</td></tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="(key,user) in users"  ng-style="myStyle"  ng-class="{active: user.isChecked}">
                      <blockquote><td><input type ="checkbox" ng-model="user.isChecked" ng-class="active">{{key+1}}</td><td>{{user.name}}</td> 


        <td>{{user.email}}</td><td>{{user.dob }}  </td> <td>{{contact }}</td><td><a href="" ng-click="removeUser(user)"  > remove | </a><a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor($index)" >  Edit user</a></td> 
                     </input>

                  <input type="button" value="Red" ng-click="myStyle={background:'red'}">     

                    </blockquote> </tr>  
                      </tbody></table>
```

Comment: on checking a row the class of that row should be active but it isnt happening 

.active{
    color: red;
}

Comment: can you create plnkr for your question?